# iPhone - NSMutableArray - UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uitableview

**Hello Folks**

I have a table view which I am loading from a JSON output. I have implemented a functionality of checking and unchecking the UITableView cells.

**Problem1** - When I scroll to the bottom of the view, all the selected cells on the top become unselected. I don't know why is that happening, if someone could guide me with that :)

**Problem2** - I want to grab all the selected cells in the tableview, and put them into a NSMutableArray. I know there are so many ways to do this but could you guys tell me a more efficient way. I spent almost 2 days figuring this out but still no luck!

Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: 'a more efficient way'? You need to tell us what you consider 'less efficient' to begin with -- what have you tried already, or looked at?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is happing because you probalbly don't yet full grasp how the UITableView works.

It reuses cells, thats why you call the `dequeTableCellWithIdentifier:` method on the `UITableView`. This means that it will reuse one of the cells not longer in view.

Don't add a `UITableViewCell` for every item in your `UITableViewDataSource`, this could/will use up to much memory and your `UITabelView` will feel very slow.

Just make sure that the datasource holds all the data you need for the object, not the `UITableViewCell`. Meaning title, selected states, ...

What you need to do is set the selected state of the cell in `UITableViewDataSource` item and look for the selected stated in the `UITableViewDataSource` and not the `UITableViewCell`.

So in the object the you retrieve from the JSON add a property selected which takes a BOOL.

Then in `UITableViewDataSoutrce` method  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SomeCellIdentiefier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (SongTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        //Load new cell
    }

    YouJSONObject *item = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (item.selecte) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

}
```

Then your `UITableViewDelegate` methods `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do something like:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
YouJSONObject *item = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    item.selected = !item.selected;
    if (item.selecte) {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```